# How can I add a tracklist to a .mp3 file

Tags: audio, mp3, id3

Recently I downloaded some music mixes from youtube to listen when I'm offline but often I want to know the music name and I can't put all of them on the file name. But recently when I was playing the monstercat podcast on VLC I saw it has the tracklist on the file, how can I do this?

image of vlc:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean, you want to add an image to your mp3s, is it right? Well you can try with Mp3Tag or even with Windows Media Player.

Here is [how to do it with Mp3Tag](http://techstrick.blogspot.it/2012/01/how-to-add-image-or-picture-to-mp3.html);

and here [with Windows Media Player](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-or-Put-a-New-Album-Cover-Photo-for-a-MP3-Song-on-Windows-7).